# php string => float casting not working

Tags: php, casting, multiplication

I have 2 numbers in strings

```
$xml = "13.52";
$value = "2";
```

and i want to multiply them.

i have tried:

```
$subtotal = $xml * $value;
```

Based on the manual, this should work. I've already tried

```
$subtotal = (float)$xml * (float)$value;
```

and

```
$xml = floatval($xml);
$value = floatval($value);
$subtotal = $xml * $value;
```

I have no idea what i have broken. There is no other help in the manual.

EDIT: looking at the html-source for the variables, it seems there was part of the xml () attached to the variable. Thanks for the help clearing my mind.

Comment: It works for me: 
`php > $x = "13.45";
php > $y = "5";php > $z = $x*$y;
php > var_dump($z);
float(67.25)
php > `

Comment: `$subtotal = $xml * $value;` should work

Comment: whats the value you are getting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your problem is where you think it is?

Based on the follow code, I get:

```
<?php
    $xml = "13.52";
    $value = "2";

    $subtotal = $xml * $value;
    echo $subtotal."<br>";

    $subtotal = (float)$xml * (float)$value;
    echo $subtotal."<br>";

    $xml = floatval($xml);
    $value = floatval($value);
    $subtotal = $xml * $value;
    echo $subtotal."<br>";
?>

27.04
27.04
27.04
```

For the most part, PHP is exceptionally forgiving when it comes to typecasting/juggling.

Comment: But why work in your first section, Basically, the $xml and $value are string. so why it works @Fluffeh

Comment: @imran Because PHP is clever enough to try to accomodate that oversight for you and converts them into ints/floats before it does the math :)